# In Perl, can you subclass and hook all parent-class functions without `AUTOLOAD`?

Tags: perl, module, vectorization, subclass

I'm writing a subclass that encapsulates multiple objects of the parent class so I can call functions sort-of like a vector, something like this:

```perl
package OriginalClass;

sub new { return bless {bar => 123}, 'OriginalClass' }

sub foo { return shift->{bar}; }
1;


package NewClass;
use parent OriginalClass;

# Return a blessed arrayref of "OriginalClass" objects.
# new() would be called NewClass->new(OriginalClass->new(), ...)
sub new { 
  my $class = shift;

  return bless \@_, 'NewClass';
}

# Vectorized foo(), returns a list of SUPER::foo() results:
sub foo
{
  my $self = shift;
  my @ret;

  push @ret, $_->SUPER::foo() foreach @$self;

  return @ret;
}

1;
```

I don't want to write a new vectorized function in `NewClass` for each function in `OriginalClass`, particularly for when `OriginalClass` adds new functions to be maintained (vectorized) in `NewClass`.

**Question:**

As I understand `AUTOLOAD` is slow, so is there a way to vectorize calls `OriginalClass` via something like `NewClass` without `AUTOLOAD`?

Comment: This isn't an inheritance relationship. Remove the inheritance, and use `$_->foo()`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> As I understand `AUTOLOAD` is slow

If `AUTOLOAD` generates the missing sub, then only the first call is "slow" since subsequent calls of the same method don't result in `AUTOLOAD` being called at all.

```perl
package NewClass;

use strict;
use warnings;

sub new {
   my $class = shift;
   return bless( \@_, $class );
}

sub AUTOLOAD {
   my $method_name = our $AUTOLOAD =~ s/^.*:://sr;

   my $method = sub {
      my $self = shift;
      return map { $_->$method_name( @_ ) } @$self;
   };

   {
      no strict 'refs';
      *$method_name = $method;
   }

   goto &$method;
}

1
```

Note that I didn't use `parent` and `SUPER::`. This isn't an inheritance relationship. And it would prevent `AUTOLOAD` from getting called since `AUTOLOAD` is only called when a method doesn't exist.

You can use Sub::Name to "name the sub" for better diagnostics.

```perl
use Sub::Name qw( subname );

my $method = subname $method_name => sub { ... };
```

---

But yes, `AUTOLOAD` can be avoided here, as long as you can get a list of the method names in advance.

```perl
package NewClass;

use strict;
use warnings;

sub new {
   my $class = shift;
   return bless( \@_, $class );
}

for my $method_name (qw( foo ... )) {
   my $method = sub {
      my $self = shift;
      return map { $_->$method_name( @_ ) } @$self;
   };

   no strict 'refs';
   *$method_name = $method;
}

1
```

The above uses a hardcoded list, but more dynamic solutions are possible. For example, the list could be obtained from inspecting the contents of the OriginalClass namespace for subs (filtering out `new` and anything else inappropriate such as names starting with `_`).

Comment: Please see this follow-up question, too: https://stackoverflow.com/q/74455821/14055985 .  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Module https://metacpan.org/pod/Array::Delegate could be helpful : it delegates method calls to an array of objects.

Comment: Neat!  Actually thats what I was thinking of writing, except with making AUTOLOAD define subs like @ikegami suggested.  I also wanted to returned blessed arrayref's so you the resulting arrays would be vectorized.