# Perl $AUTOLOAD evaluation in v5.10 says "Bareword found where operator expected"...but v5.26 works fine

Tags: perl, autoload

I'm using an `AUTOLOAD` example from [@ikegami's post here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74229589/14055985). A recent [CPAN testers report](http://www.cpantesters.org/cpan/report/5bde02fe-652a-11ed-abf4-11073d6a6173) for my [RF::Component::Multi](https://metacpan.org/pod/RF::Component::Multi) module says:

```
Bareword found where operator expected at .../RF/Component/Multi.pm line 102, near "s/^.*:://sr"
syntax error at .../RF/Component/Multi.pm line 102, near "s/^.*:://sr"
```

The code is below and [here](https://github.com/KJ7LNW/perl-RF-Component/blob/master/lib/RF/Component/Multi.pm#L98) on GitHub.

- What is it that Perl 5.10 doesn't like?
- Is there a Perl feature requiring >5.10 hidden in here that I'm missing? (My Perl 5.26.3 is working)

  - If so can it be made more backwards compatible? How?
  - If not, where do I find the version so I can do the right `use 5.xx`?
- Do I need `use vars '$AUTOLOAD'`?

```perl
# Thanks @ikegami:
# https://stackoverflow.com/a/74229589/14055985
sub AUTOLOAD
{
    my $method_name = our $AUTOLOAD =~ s/^.*:://sr;

    my $method = sub {
        my $self = shift;
        return [ map { $_->$method_name(@_) } @$self ];
    };

    {
        no strict 'refs';
        *$method_name = $method;
    }

    goto &$method;
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`s///r` was added in 5.14.

```perl
my $method_name = our $AUTOLOAD =~ s/^.*:://sr;
```

could be replaced with

```perl
( my $method_name = our $AUTOLOAD ) =~ s/^.*:://s;
```

Answer (score 7):

You can use [Perl::MinimumVersion](https://metacpan.org/dist/Perl-MinimumVersion) to answer questions like this.

```
$ perlver your-code.pl


   --------------------------------------
 | file   | explicit | syntax  | external |
 | -------------------------------------- |
 | minver | ~        | v5.13.2 | n/a      |
 | -------------------------------------- |
 | Minimum explicit version : ~           |
 | Minimum syntax version   : v5.13.2     |
 | Minimum version of perl  : v5.13.2     |
   --------------------------------------
```

And, for more details,

```
 $ perlver --blame your-code.pl

 ------------------------------------------------------------
 File    : minver
 Line    : 3
 Char    : 40
 Rule    : _regex
 Version : 5.013002
 ------------------------------------------------------------
 s/^.*:://sr
 ------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: I wish I could tick two checkboxes, this is a really good answer too.